# Some calculus Prove/Disprove question

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, solution-verification

I have 2 questions that I would like to make sure I did the first one right, and get some tips for the next one :)

Prove or disprove:

1. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. If the equation $f'(x)=0$ has exactly one solution, then the equation $f(x)=0$ has at least two solutions.

I think this one is false, because I can take $f(x)=x^2$. It is clear that the function is differentiable, and $f'(x)=2x$, so the equation $f'(x)=0$ has only one solution as needed, when $x=0$.

And the equation $f(x)=0$ has only one solution, when $x=0$, which is in contradiction to the fact that $f(x)=0$ has at least two solutions.

--

2. Let $f:[a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x \to b^-}f(x)$ does not exist in the extended sence.
   Then  there exists an $x_{0} \in [a,b)$ for which $f'(x_{0})=0$.

So I have tried to think for functions that I know which for their limits does not exist, like $\cos (\frac{1}{x})$, and started playing with them, but no matter what I did, $f'$ always had a point $x_{0}$ which for $f'(x_{0})=0$. So I think that this statement is true, but if you guys can please enlighten me, I will very appreciate that!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** if $f'(x) \neq 0$ on $[a,b),$ then $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ on $[a,b).$
What can you conclude from this information?

(We don't implicitly require $f'$ to be continuous here! See theorem 5.12 in Rudin's Principles.)

**Edit:**
Suppose that $f'(x)>0$ on $[a,b).$ Then by the mean value theorem, $f$ is increasing. It follows that $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = \sup_{x \in [a,b)} f(x),$
so the limit exists in the extended sense. The case $f'(x) < 0 $ is similar. This proves the contrapositive of the statement.

Comment: That $f$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. So $f$ is going up and down near $b$, so it alternates between increasing / decreasing, so $f'$ must has a value where $f'(x_{0})=0$?

Comment: @MathLover Indeed $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing, but the idea is to conclude from this that the limit $x \to b^-$ does exist, which proves the contrapositive.

Comment: Ok I think that I understand that, so assuming towards contradiction that $f'(x_{0}) \ne 0$ for every $x_{0} \in [a,b)$, and then showing for both sides that the limit indeed exists, so we can surely say that there exists $x_{0} \in [a,b)$ such that $f'(x_{0})=0$?

Comment: @MathLover yes; in other words, if the limit doesn't exist, $f'(x)$ has to be zero somewhere, because if it weren't, we explicitly show that it does have a limit.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!! About the first question, do you think that I did it right?

Comment: @MathLover you're welcome, and yes that looks correct to me!

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven! Have a wonderful day ahead! :D

Comment: Thanks, you too